# Excel VBA - command button on userform to place value in specific cell based on 4 criteria (across 3 worksheets)

Tags: vba, excel

I'm extremely new working with VBA. I'm trying to create a file to help analyze actual, budget and forecast values for my finance department. I think VBA is the way I need to go to get my idea to work like I envision, but finding someone who knows VBA has been quite a challenge. I've tried different searches, but I don't think I've phrased my searches correctly to get the information I need. I would appreciate any help I can get.

What I have so far: A userform with a command button where the criteria can be set along with the value.

What I need it to do:  When using the command button the value will go to 1 of 3 worksheets into a designated cell based on the 4 criteria.

Here are my criteria (and their possibilities):

1. Month (1-12)
2. Entry Type (Actual, Budget, Forecast)
3. FCV Header (Raw Materials, Packaging Materials….)
4. Variance Type (Usage, Price, Substitution…)

I have 4 worksheets

1. Input Tab (this is where the command button is to open the userform and gives an outline of the different Header/Variance Type combinations that can be used)
2. FCV Actual
3. FCV Budget
4. FCV Forecast

I want the “Upload FCV” command button in the userform to look at those 4 criteria and place the value from the text box in the appropriate cell.

- The coding I’m troubleshooting right now is for the following setup. The proper cell for this entry to populate is on the FCV Actual tab cell C12
- Month: 1
- Entry Type: Actual
- FCV Header: Raw Materials
- Variance Type: Usage
- Text Box Value: 100

I then want the userform to clear itself in preparation for the next entry.
This is the coding I have so far.

```
'Sub UseModeless()'
    'Dim frm As New UserFormData_Entry_Form'
    'frm.Show vbModeless'
'End Sub'

'Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()'
    'CB_Month.List = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12)'
    'CB_Entry_Type.List = Array("Actual", "Budget", "Forecast")'
    'CB_FCV_Header.List = Array("Raw Materials", "Packaging Materials", "Labour/Other Variable Variances", "Energy", "Fixed Cost Variances", "Depreciation", "Volume", "PRO")'
    'CB_Variance_Type.List = Array("Usage", "Price", "Substitution", "Usage & Non Prop & Other Variable", "Substitution & Costing Lot Size", "Fixed Labour & Salaried", "Maintenance (inc. Labour)", "Fixed Energy Variances", "Fixed Costs Other", "Fixed Spend - Not Explained", "Start Up", "Special Charges", "Bad Goods", "Cost Without Production", "Factory FG Write-Offs Due to Quality", "N/A")'
'End Sub'

'Private Sub Upload_Button_Click()'
    'Application.ScreenUpdating = False'
    'Dim WS As Worksheet'
    'If CB_Month = "1" And CB_Entry_Type = "Actual" And CB_FCV_Header = "Raw Materials" And CB_Variance_Type = "Usage" And TB_Test <> "" Then'
    'Set WS = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("FCV Actual")'
    'Sheets("input tab").Range("a1") = TB_Total.Value'
    'End If'
    'UserForm = Me.reset()'
'End Sub'
```

Comment: What is the specific problem you're having?  It's unlikely anyone is going to analyse your posted code against your requirements to figure out what the problem is.   Direct questions - one specific problem at a time - are the best approach when asking for help here.

Comment: It's the last portion of code I've got at the moment:

Comment: It's the last portion of code I've got at the moment. I think it's something to do with the "if" statement and "Set WS". If I take those 2 lines out, I can get it to work.

Comment: Always helps to explain exactly what errors you're seeing, or how actual behavior is different from expected behavior.  We can't really guess the problem.